# How to pass data in sidebar just after calling toggelsidebar()

Tags: javascript, xul

I want to fill some data in sidebar just after it opens.

But here my program say's that--

document.getElementById("sidebarElement").value ------is Empety

```
    togglesidebar("viewSidebar");

    document.getElementById("sidebarElement").value="somevalue";
```

So what I can do in this condition. Please suggest.

---

**Thanks for your replies,**

I got the reason that why my sidebar textboxes doesn't fill with data after calling togglesidebar().

Here is a little snapshot of my code that what I am trying to do.

**On overlay.js file:**

```
function displaySidebar()
{
  toggleSidebar('vieweSidebar',false);
  val1="some string";
  val2="some string";
  myfun(val1,val2);// not calling
}
```

**On mySidebar.js file:**

```
myfun(val1,val2)
{
 document.getElementById("textbox1").value=val1;
 document.getElementById("textbox2").value=val2;
}
```

Here function **myfun(val1,val2)** is not calling after calling **togglesidebar('viewSidebar',false)**.

So I am not able to fill textboxes on sidebar just after calling togglesidebar.

Can You tell me reason that why myfun() is not calling here.

**textbox1 and textbox2 are sidebar elements.**

Comment: The sidebar will load asynchronously, it won't be magically done the instant you call `togglesidebar`. It might be easier for the sidebar to call a function from the main window when it loads, not for the main window to wait for the sidebar to load.